# ionic contact select not working correctly

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, contacts

I have a problem in ionic when I want to open the contacts.

The funny thing is that contacts only open when before clicking to get_contacts() I tab into/activate the textarea. After that the function get_contacts() is working fine - contacts popup as it should.

But only clicking the button (I added two in my container) does not open the contacts - nothing happens. Why????

Here is my code of the container:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages" class="message-wrapper rlt"
     on-hold="onMessageHold($event, $index, message)">

    ....

</div>
```

```
<form name="sendMessageForm" ng-submit="sendMessage(sendMessageForm)" style="background-color: black;" novalidate>
    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable message-footer" style="background-color: black;" keyboard-attach>
      <div class="footer-btn-wrap">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-attach" ng-click="choosePhoto()"></button>
      </div>
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <textarea ng-model="input.message" value="" placeholder="Leave a message..."
                  required minlength="1" maxlength="1500" msd-elastic  autofocus></textarea>
      </label>
      <div class="footer-btn-wrap">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-send footer-btn" type="submit"
                ng-disabled="!input.message || input.message === ''">
        </button>
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-search-strong" ng-click="get_contacts()">
            </button>
      </div>
    </ion-footer-bar>

</form>
```

And this is my js......

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

    $scope.get_contacts = function (){

    navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact){
    console.log('The following contact has been selected:' + JSON.stringify(contact));
    var mobilenr = " no mobile nr ";
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(contact));
    for (i = 0; i < jsonObj.phoneNumbers.length; i++) {
        var phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers[i];
        if (phoneNumber.type == 'mobile')
            {

                mobilenr = phoneNumber.value;

            }

        }

        $scope.itemsList.push({"name":contact.name.formatted, "room":mobilenr});

        localStorage.setItem("phonecounter",+localStorage.getItem("phonecounter")+1);

        },function(err){
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        });

    }

}, false)
```

I'm not able to get this thing working, googled and tried almost everything.

Does anybody have a hint?

I tested on iOS - but this should work in any environment, as I understand. Or not?

Thank you in advance - very much